# Repeating results in grouped sort on pagination with skip and limit

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have the following aggregate query to sort grouped data and return it in pages:

```
Product.aggregate([
  { $match : { categories : category, brand : { $ne: null } }},
  { $group : { _id : '$brand', rating: { $max: '$rating' } } },
  { $sort : { rating : -1 } },
  { $skip : skip },
  { $limit : limit }], function(error, results){
    ....
  })
```

This is meant to find the brands of the products with the input category and with a brand, group them by brand, and sort the brand groups by the highest rated product in the brand group. This is then meant to be paginated, using skip and limit parameters.

When I paginate it I end up getting occasional results repeating (just one group every now and then, I haven't noticed a pattern). I know that the data does not include repeated products, and none of the data is changing between calls, so what am I doing wrong with the query to get these results?

Comment: Well, since you are sorting by rating, if it changes between queries that can happen.

Comment: Edited to add that the data is not changing between queries, thanks for the suggestion though @joao.

Comment: Hmmm, can you try changing the sort to { $sort : { rating : -1, "_id": 1} } and see how it goes?

Comment: You're right, there's several products with the same maximum rating, and it seems I can't rely on the sort order, but sorting by _id as well solved that problem! I'll accept an answer if you want to write one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue in the aggregation is linked to the case when there are several brands with the same rating. In that case, you cannot guarantee that those will appear in the same order.

The solution is to force a *brand* sort for the equal *rating* cases:

```
{ $sort : { rating : -1, "_id" : 1 } }
```